# Jest's coverage reports with ES6' export expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, istanbul

I've got some issues with **Jest**'s built-in coverage tool **Istanbul**. 
I'm using features of the ES6 standard, like the `export` expression. The tests runs all perfect with the expected result. Simply the coverage report is slightly buggy. So when using the `export` expression – not the `export default` – the highlighting in the HTML report seems to be corrupt. Only the last function with the leading `export` expression get highlighted in the expected manner.

To visualize the issue, I've got two screenshots of the reports. I've changed the order of the functions, so you'll see it quite well:

[image]
[image]

The setup and the test specification is unmodified. Though I'm using **webpack** in this project, I've got the some issue in a simple ES6 project. So I would exclude reason related to the bundler.

---

Here some information about the system:

- node: 4.2.6
- npm: 2.14.12

And the – imho – relevant dependencies:

```
"babel": "^6.5.1",
"babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
"babel-core": "^6.5.1",
"babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^9.0.3",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
"babel-register": "^6.7.2",
"jest-cli": "^0.9.2",
"webpack": "^1.12.2",
```

---

Have anyone an idea what's the problem and how to solve it? Would love to stay with **Jest** because it was really easy to integrate. Hope I'm not alone and there's a solution :)

Best regards and happy easter!

Comment: Seeing the same issue in a React Native project. Wish I could help :/

Comment: @TomA: I opened an issue in the related GitHub project. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/841 – but I'll let you know as soon as there's a solution/fix :)